# Multiple TextField's in Animate CC? Can't add second TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe

I have a very simple apps with LocalConnection between them. One button in client and one Dynamic Text on server. When I pushing my button on client then  text in server are changing, everything works good. But if I add static text in server then my dynamic text stop working (not changing). How is it possible? Checked its 5 times, just adding static text ruined my app.

Sry, for my English, Im not fluent speaker.

p.s Woorking in Animate CC

p.p.s. feels that is very simple solution here but checked it in google and didnt found any answers :(

**SERVER**

```
import flash.net.LocalConnection;

var conn:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();

conn.client = this;
conn.connect("data");

function recieve_data(unfO:String):void {
    unfOne.text = unfO;
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
import flash.net.LocalConnection;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var conn:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
var unfOned:int = 0;

unfOne.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, unfOne_send);

function unfOne_send(e:MouseEvent):void {
    unfOned++;
    conn.send('data', 'recieve_data', unfOned);
    unfOne_caption.text = unfOned.toString();
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*if I add static text in server*"?

Comment: I mean: when I just add new Text in 'server' app by Text tool

Comment: How do you add that textfield? What else are you changing? Do you get any error messages in the output panel?

Comment: I just using Text Tool for it, with Static text in Properties. No errors :(

Comment: Hey there, no need to add the solution to your question. Posting it as an answer as you did is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in Font, by default it was Open Sans and I should change it to arial or do Font Embeding.